# Prove that $|\Phi(p)|^2 \propto\sin^2\left( \frac{p L}{\hbar}\right) $

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, fourier-transform, wave-equation

I can not prove the following with the properties of the trigonometric functions. Let

$$
p_{\pm}=\frac{pL}{\hbar}\pm n\pi.
$$

I have the following expression:

$$
\Phi(p)=L\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi L \hbar}}\frac{e^{-\frac{ip_{+}}{2}}}{p_{+}p_{-}} \left [ (-1)^{n}p_{+}\sin \left( \frac{p_{-}}{2}\right)- \sin\left( \frac{p_+}{2}\right) \right].
$$

I need to prove that:

$$
|\Phi(p)| ^{2}\propto\sin^2\left( \frac{p L}{\hbar}\right).
$$

Comment: Is the argument of $\sin$ $\frac{p_-}{2}-\frac{p_+}{2}$ or just $\frac{p_-}{2}$?

Comment: You title is different with what you asked for.............